# Subscribing to a topic from an actor

Tags: akka, apache-kafka

How would you go about subscribing to a kafka topic using akka actors?

From what I understand the kafka consumer will make a socket connection to kafka.  When a message comes into the subscribed topic, then kafka will send a signal back and "wake-up" the consumer and it will pull from the topic. Is this theoritically the way it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consumer clients are not notified about writes.

Kafka has a pure pull-based consumer model. A consumer client needs to actively `poll()` Kafka brokers to check for new messages. This is usually done in a loop until you terminate your client.

Comment: so with akka, you would create a schedular to poll every x seconds?

Comment: I am not familiar with Akka, but sounds reasonable to me.